# html2canvas not grabbing svg

Tags: javascript, jquery, html2canvas

When I run this:

```
html2canvas(document.body, {
allowTaint: true,
  onrendered: function(canvas) {
    document.body.appendChild(canvas);
  }
});
```

I have my whole page grabbed into a canvas, but the `SVG` isn't. Been looking around but I couldn't find anything helpful to solve it, any idea?

Comment: it is not rendering the leafletmap like this one http://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth/example.html nor D3 mindmap

Comment: Updated [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2h2ssh7k/14/). Could you take a look?

Comment: @gaetanoM ok thats' great, could it a matter of setTimeout then? because when I do it on my page it captures everything but the svg while in your jFiddle works

Comment: That's right. You need to wait for completion of leafletjs image rendering.... I hope this will help you. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved it by telling [leaflet to provide tiles as canvas](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#canvas) and not as an `svg`

```
jQuery("#print").on("click", function() {
    myCapture();
});

function myCapture() {
  html2canvas(document.body, {
    allowTaint: true,
    useCORS: true,
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
      document.body.appendChild(canvas);
    }
  });
}

   var map = L.map('map', {
        renderer: L.canvas()
});
```